# MySQL simple slow query on date but fast on char

Tags: mysql, date

I've been searching all over but haven't seen a satisfactory solution. So can somebody help..

I have asimple table with a simple query that is taking a long time. I am using version 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.13.04.1 (It's actually Linux Mint Olivia. Also I switched to MariaDB but it didn't seem to make any difference.)

I created a test table to demonstrate:

mysql> show create table test;

```
| test | CREATE TABLE `test` (
`sym` char(5) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
`date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`vol` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin |
```

I then filled it with 11 million rows from another table. If I add an index on 'sym' a simple

```
'SELECT * FROM test WHERE Sym='ORCL';
```

shows

6467 rows in set (0.10 sec)

I then add an index on date and it takes much longer for something like:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE Date='2008-10-1';
```

2488 rows in set (12.40 sec)

This is suspiciously close to the time without the index, and the hard drive light is on for the duration of the query.

I have tried USE INDEX and even FORCE INDEX but it seems to have no effect.

```
BTW SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test WHERE Date='2008-10-1';
```

returns

```
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
| 2488     |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

And if I just ask for the date field then

```
SELECT date from test where date=20081020;
```

it comes back with the correct number of rows in about 0.30 sec, so it's using the index for that.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test WHERE Date='2008-10-1';
```

shows (I called the Date index 'dt')

```
+------+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| 1    | SIMPLE | test | ref | dt | dt | 4 | const | 2445 | |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+-------+
```

Notice the Extra column is blank. Same for USE INDEX and FORCE INDEX.

Can anyone tell me why this takes so long? Let me know if I can provide more information.

Comment: How large is the database? And is the connection over the network?

Comment: In the explain you provided... shouldn't the `extra` falgs contain `Using where`?

Comment: @JamesLee "I then filled it with 11 million rows" he already said how large.

Comment: +1 for empirical testing methods: `hard drive light is on`

Comment: @James Lee The server and client are on the same machine. Thanks to Jorge for answering how large.

Comment: @Mosty Yes, that is a mystery that there is nothing in the Extra column and maybe part of the problem. The EXPLAIN for the char field lookup 'sym' contains "Using index condition"

Comment: I solved my problem (I think, I will see if it causes problems down the road). I created a new test table with the date stored as char(8) (i.e.YYYYmmdd) and it flies as fast as the other select on the 'sym' field. I don't feel as though the original question has been answered. I find it hard to believe that it would take 124 times as long to do a SELECT on a DATE type.

Comment: Forget the above comment. I must have been the victim of caching. I was trying to SELECT on random date strings, but when I rebooted the machine it went to multiple seconds just like the SELECT on DATE type. SELECT on 'sym' still looks to be very fast.